# nest home simulator -- sample apps

Tags: nest-api

I am looking forward to create a UiMagician binding for NEST users. At present UiMagician have binding for VSCP iot project.
https://sites.google.com/site/uimagician/

Please suggest right path for documentation for gateway agent so that REST communication can be establish to communicate with REST device.

Also if some reference example javascript code is available then please suggest the right link.

NEST home simulator does it create the virtual device or it create a HTML app to controll the devices.
https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/home-simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator is to create virtual devices for testing. You login with a new nest account and you can add devices and locations.

[Link to Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nest-home-simulator/jmcapoebgeaabepohkchkldlfhchkega)

There are also Javascript code samples [here](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/sample-code)

What you need to decide is whether you will do REST polling or have a real-time REST Streaming/Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for replying .. Is their some standard document to understand the REST packet format used to define device & its parameter ... how is the content of this packet format generated  ..https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference  .. means to say which document is taken into refrence to generate this data object

Comment: The API reference shows the possible parameters for each state. Everything is formatted in JSON.

Comment: But google nest may be having a standard to define state for devices .. where can i find documentation for this ..??

Comment: https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference is the definition of states. Just click on "Devices" on the left under "Data Model" You can also see it long form here https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/api-overview

Comment: Thanks, Ok so once this JSON object is created .. who will use it ?? Will it be used by NEST home automation server ... ?? If yes then how to load it to their server ??

Comment: You use HTTP GET to get the status of the devices from the Nest server and you use HTTP PUT to change the status of certain states. Check out this quick start guide https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/rest-quick-guide/

Comment: thanks for your support .. just want to clarify one point that .. where will this JSON object go ... will it be loaded to the device which runs REST home automation server ???